# How do I check if input is one word or 2 separated by delimiter "-"

Tags: awk, ksh

I need help with the following `ksh` script:

```
ExpResult=`echo "$LoadString" | awk -F"-" '{print NF}'=2`

MinExp=`echo "$ExpResult" | tr -s " " | sed 's/^[ ]//g'| cut -d"-" -f1`
MaxExp=`echo "$ExpResult" | tr -s " " | sed 's/^[ ]//g'| cut -d"-" -f2`
```

I can get an input as two options : "50-100" or "50" (for example)

I have two questions:

1. How do I check if the input is "one word" or two words separated by delimiter "-"?
2. If the input is two words, how can I separate them?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than call an external program to parse your input, you can use the internal `case` statement to validate input and parameter expansion features to convert your input, i.e.

```
 # set a copy/paste value for $1
 set -- 50-10

 case "$1" in
  *-* ) 
    range="$1"
    min="${range%-*}"
    max="${range#*-}"
 ;;
 * )
   singleNum="$1"
 ;;
esac
echo min=$min ... max=$max
```

**output**

```
min=50 ... max=100
```

Try for non-pair

```
unset min max 
set -- other values
case ...
echo min= ... max= ... singleNum=$singleNum
```

**output**

```
min= ... max= ... singleNum=other
```

---

Hopefully the case processing is self-explanatory, but the parameter expansion may require a little explanation.

The statement

```
  min=${range%-*}
```

says remove from the right side of the expanded value (50-100) anything starting at the last `-` until the end of the string. This leaves the value `50` remaining.

The reverse happens with

```
max=${range#*-}
```

Says remove from the left side of the expanded value anything up to the first `-` char. This leaves the `100`.

As there is only one `-` char in this string, you don't need to worry about the other versions of `${var##*-}` which says remove all from the left until the **last** match of `-`, and the reverse `${var%%-*}` , remove all from right (backwards) until the very first `-` char.

---

The fanatical minimalists will remind us that this can be done without a temporary variable, i.e.

```
  min=${1%-*} ; max=${1#*-}
```

And the one-line fantasists can be satisfied with

```
case "$1" in *-* ) range="$1";min="${range%-*}";max="${range#*-}";;* ) singleNum="$1";;esac; echo min=$min ... max=$max .,, singleNum=$singleNum
```

:-)

IHTH

Comment: Splitting with `IFS='-'` also comes to mind. Then you can use the shell's built-in `$#` to find the number of tokens.

Comment: @tripleee : good idea. Haven't heard back from O.P., so don't if I'd be wasting more of my time for an answer that isn't helping or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
LoadString=$1
MinExp=`echo "$LoadString" | awk -F"-" '{if (NF==2) print $1}`
MaxExp=`echo "$LoadString" | awk -F"-" '{if (NF==2) print $2}`
echo $MinExp
echo $MaxExp
```

eg:

```
user@host:/tmp/test$ ksh test.ksh 50-100
50
100
```